# How do I align information on tables using html on umbraco?

Tags: html, css, umbraco

How do I go about lining up the information on the tables as per the image attached on umbraco?

Below is the link to the image:

[table-alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tg8x7.jpg)

Comment: don't they have a documentation for that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about aligning tables which have been created in the RTE (rich text editor), then you may simply be able to change the columns widths manually.

Otherwise, you may need to have a custom solution developed.